# Wondering what my countertop is made of

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops

The previous owner installed this countertop, who cannot be reached.  I have no idea what kind of counter this is and wonder if I should be treating it, what I should clean it with, etc.

It does seem quite porous. When I wipe it with a damp cloth it is shiny and very quickly turns matte.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the edge? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few people do.

Comment: Is there actual texture on it, or is that just an illusion? Is it cold to the touch like stone?

Comment: Yes...it has quite a bit of texture and is cold to the touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many hardware stores have swatches of laminate and other countertop material you can bring home. Take some home and compare visually, and after washing. Home Depot, for example, shows "Durable [clink vinyl plank](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Take-Home-Sample-Reclaimed-Wood-Grey-Click-Vinyl-Plank-4-in-x-4-in-S030HDBL491/304057478) with reclaimed grey hardwood look", looking something like your good photo.

Usually, samples picked up in-store are free.

Comment: I know it isn't vinyl or laminate.  I can tell by the undermount sink and looking at the underside of the extension of the breakfast bar.  It would be good to know if it is granite, quartz....someone suggested it may be soapstone??

Comment: Note that this does not have a wood appearance. The lines are too varied, there's no "plank" effect, and there's no knots.

Comment: Soapstone is rather soft.  You can carve soapstone with a knife.  Looks more like a natural product like granite - not quartz, IMO.